# C++ replace листа QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, строки, замена

Есть функция, которая принимает 2 аргумента - `QStringList` и `QString`, где в листе содержится n-e количество строк и каждую четвертую строку из листа необходимо заменить строкой `QString` и в итоге вернуть `QStringList` с замененными строками.

Comment: Здесь не делают за других учебные задания.

Comment: А в чем, собственно проблема ? Или Вы хотите это сделать как-то так, чтобы было совсем "коротенько" ?

Comment: да нет, проблема в том что я пока не вижу путь решения. Да может для большинства здесь находящихся это легко, но я пока только учусь.  Пробую пока через итератор сделать цикл foreach - где оно будет заменять выбранные значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то я сегодня добрый... Если только учитесь, то держите.

С модификацией исходного списка:

```
QStringList& f1(QStringList& list, const QString& string) {
    for (size_t i = 3; i < list.size(); i += 4)
         list[i] = string;
    return list;
}
```

С созданием копии исходного списка:

```
QStringList f2(const QStringList& list, const QString& string) {
    QStringList result;
    result.reserve(list.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        result.push_back(i % 4 == 3 ? string : list[i]);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо - сейчас буду изучать). Честно говоря не ожидал что помогут.